# Attach Pdf from Assets in email

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I tried to send in email a pdf as attachment, the problem is that when I check the email there is no file attached.

```
public class Commandes_Consommables extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView Commandes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_commandes__consommables);
        PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.commande);
        pdfView.fromAsset("grille_consommables.pdf")
                .enableSwipe(true) // allows to block changing pages using swipe
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false) // render annotations (such as comments, colors or forms)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true) // improve rendering a little bit on low-res screens
                // spacing between pages in dp. To define spacing color, set view background
                .spacing(0)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load();
        
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.attach, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.attach:
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
                String shareBody = "Bonjour";
                String shareSubject = "Retour SAV";
                String shareDestinatination = "marketing@saaa.fr";
                Uri pdfConsommables = Uri.parse("assets/grille_consommables.pdf");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfConsommables);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubject);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, shareDestinatination);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "partager avec"));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the code is running well but when I am in the email I have the email body the destination adress and I have this message it is impossible to attch files.

Comment: `Uri pdfConsommables = Uri.parse("assets/grille_consommables.pdf");` The email application can not read from that uri. Now before you send such an uri to another application you could try for yourself if you could open an input stream for that uri and read from it.

Comment: `tried to send in email a pdf as attachment` You forgot 'from assets' there.

Comment: I tried with: sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(new File("C:/Users/Barry_a/sub/app/src/main/assets/cgv.pdf")));  and does not work

Comment: You have not reacted to my first comment. Nor did you edit your post like second comment.

Comment: Can you please explain to us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: ... and to kotlin? And to java? And to android-studio?